# sql query not firing from within object method in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to test the connection to a local database -

```
 $database = array(
"hostname"=>'localhost',
"username"=>'root',
"password"=>'root',
"database"=>'mydb'
);

 /**
 * 
 */
 class Book
 {  
private $book_id;
private $dbLink;

function __construct($book_id)
{
    $this->book_id=$book_id;
    $this->dbLink = mysqli_connect($database['hostname'],$database['username'],$database['password'],$database['database']) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($this->dbLink));
    //var_dump($this->dbLink);
}

function qBook(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM books";
    var_dump($this->dbLink->query($query));     
}

 }//class

$book = new Book(3);
$book->qBook();
```

Now, the problem is that I do get the dbLink object properly but the query doesnt return any resource. But having the same query run in the file, outside the object fetches the query. 
FYI, I am running the script from the command line. Is there something I am missing out on?

Comment: any error you got in the script? you have to pass $book_id as parameter while creating an object of `Book` class or make `__construct($book_id==null)`

Comment: ignore that..passing it in the constructor manually for testing..forgot to write it above..

Comment: was too preoccupied trying to fix the issue thinking it was a port problem since i was running the script from the command line..was a simple gotcha...view my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

you might get error **"var database not found"**

in constructor directly you can't use outside variables of class... so you have pass **$database** with constructor...

```
   $book = new Book(12,$database);
```

and change you **constructor** like this

```
   function __construct($book_id,$database)
   {
     $this->book_id=$book_id;
     $this->dbLink =  mysqli_connect($database['hostname'],$database['username'],$database['password'],$database['database']) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($this->dbLink));
    //var_dump($this->dbLink);
  }
```

this way it will work...

hope it may help you

Comment: although...ur solution will work as well for people who dont want to use globals...

Answer (score 0):

an 'oops' moment.. forgot to add the following line in the constructor -

```
global $database;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 function qBook(){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM books";
 var_dump(mysqli->query($this->dbLink,$query));     
 }
```

Note: the password you providing is really "root" ? please check it out also.